# Facebook Like button showing RIGHT Title but WRONG Description and WRONG thumbnail (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-like

Okay so when I'm liking a post on my wordpress blog it's showing up on Facebook with the correct title and like to the post, but the thumbnail and description is wrong.

I'm using the following code for my likes:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
                  <script>(function(d, s, id) {
                    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
                    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=266693680020880";
                    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
                <div class="fb-like" data-href="<?php the_permalink();?>" data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" data-width="100" data-show-faces="false"></div>
```

But as I said, the description is the same for all likes (only the URL for my wordpress blog), and the thumbnail is a random one from another post.

Answer (score 0):

What do your og: meta tags say for that page being liked?

Try linting it at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint to make sure your og: tags are being read properly by Facebook.

Comment: what are og tags and where do i specify them in wordpress?

Comment: OG tags go in the `<head>` section of the DOM.  Check with wordpress's help on how to insert custom things into the `<head>` section. For more information on open graph tags see http://ogp.me